# Separating a few things with preg_split

Tags: php, regex

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to write the regex to split this.

Lets say we have the sample text:

```
15HGH(Whatever)ASD
```

I would like to break it down into the following groups (numbers, letters by themselves, and parenthesis contents)

```
15
H
G
H
Whatever
A
S
D
```

It can have any combination of the above such as:

```
15HGH
12ABCD
ABCD(Whatever)(test)
```

So far, I have gotten it to break apart either the numbers/letters or just the parenthesis part broken away.  For example, in this case:

```
<?php print_r(preg_split( "/(\(|\))/", "5(Test)(testing)")); ?>
```

It will give me

Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => Test
    [2] => testing
)

I am not really sure what to put in the regex to match on only numbers and individual characters when combined.  Any suggestions?

Comment: The pattern is giving me `Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => Test [2] => [3] => testing [4] => )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got this: [Example](http://regex101.com/r/aJ3aB4) (I don't know how is written the `\n`) but the substitution is working.

`(\d+|\w|\([^)]++\))` Not too much to explain, first tries to get a number, then a char, and if there's nothing there, tries to get a whole word between parentheses. (They can't be nested)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if preg_match_all satisfying you:

```
$text = '15HGH(Whatever)ASD';
preg_match_all("/([a-z]+)(?=\))|[0-9]+|([a-z])/i", $text, $out);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($out[0]);

Array
(
    [0] => 15
    [1] => H
    [2] => G
    [3] => H
    [4] => Whatever
    [5] => A
    [6] => S
    [7] => D
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out using [preg_match_all()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
$string = '15HGH(Whatever)(Whatever)ASD';
preg_match_all('/\(([^\)]+)\)|(\d+)|([a-z])/i', $string, $matches);

$results = array_merge(array_filter($matches[1]),array_filter($matches[2]),array_filter($matches[3]));
print_r($results);
```

`\(([^\)]+)\)` **-->** Matches everything between parenthesis

`\d+` **-->** Numbers only

`[a-z]` **-->** Single letters only

`i` **-->** Case insensitive